# Django Nginx не работают статические файлы

Tags: python, django, nginx

Не работают статические файлы, а при загрузке медиа файлов выходит ошибка 403.

nginx

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name my_domen;
    access_log  /var/log/nginx/example.log;
 
    location /static/ {
        root /root/patterson;
    } 

    location /media/ {
        root /root/patterson;
    }

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8000; 
        proxy_set_header Host $server_name;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    }
}
```

settings.py

```py
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media')

STATIC_URL = '/static/' 
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static')
```

nginx log

```
...
82.147.95.81 - - [21/May/2022:18:26:43 +0300] "GET /static/dist/img/telegram.svg HTTP/1.1" 403 196 "http://my_domen/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/101.0.4951.67 Safari/537.36"
82.147.95.81 - - [21/May/2022:18:26:43 +0300] "GET /static/dist/img/mail.svg HTTP/1.1" 403 196 "http://my_domen/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/101.0.4951.67 Safari/537.36"
82.147.95.81 - - [21/May/2022:18:26:43 +0300] "GET /static/dist/img/question.svg HTTP/1.1" 403 196 "http://my_domen/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/101.0.4951.67 Safari/537.36"
82.147.95.81 - - [21/May/2022:18:26:43 +0300] "GET /static/dist/assets/favicon.ico HTTP/1.1" 403 196 "http://my_domen/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/101.0.4951.67 Safari/537.36"
82.147.95.81 - - [21/May/2022:18:27:57 +0300] "GET /new-tracking/ HTTP/1.1" 200 2101 "http://my_domen/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/101.0.4951.67 Safari/537.36"
82.147.95.81 - - [21/May/2022:18:27:57 +0300] "GET /static/dist/img/logo_header.svg?dc43466e HTTP/1.1" 403 196 "http://my_domen/new-tracking/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/101.0.4951.67 Safari/537.36"
82.147.95.81 - - [21/May/2022:18:27:57 +0300] "GET /static/dist/css/index.css HTTP/1.1" 403 196 "http://my_domen/new-tracking/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/101.0.4951.67 Safari/537.36"
82.147.95.81 - - [21/May/2022:18:27:57 +0300] "GET /static/dist/js/index.js HTTP/1.1" 403 196 "http://my_domen/new-tracking/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/101.0.4951.67 Safari/537.36"
82.147.95.81 - - [21/May/2022:18:27:57 +0300] "GET /static/dist/img/profile.svg HTTP/1.1" 403 196 "http://my_domen/new-tracking/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/101.0.4951.67 Safari/537.36"
82.147.95.81 - - [21/May/2022:18:27:57 +0300] "GET /static/dist/img/check-complete.svg HTTP/1.1" 403 196 "http://my_domen/new-tracking/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/101.0.4951.67 Safari/537.36"
82.147.95.81 - - [21/May/2022:18:27:57 +0300] "GET /static/dist/assets/favicon.ico HTTP/1.1" 403 196 "http://my_domen/new-tracking/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/101.0.4951.67 Safari/537.36"
82.147.95.81 - - [21/May/2022:18:28:04 +0300] "GET /products/?category=gadzhety-i-elektronika HTTP/1.1" 200 271 "http://my_domen/new-tracking/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/101.0.4951.67 Safari/537.36"
82.147.95.81 - - [21/May/2022:18:28:04 +0300] "GET /media/products/img/unsplash_0a1AxtzSmWA_NW6udhV.png HTTP/1.1" 403 196 "http://my_domen/products/?category=gadzhety-i-elektronika" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/101.0.4951.67 Safari/537.36"
82.147.95.81 - - [21/May/2022:18:28:04 +0300] "GET /media/products/img/unsplash_0a1AxtzSmWA_A7HA1sk_QEnjsj4.png HTTP/1.1" 403 196 "http://my_domen/products/?category=gadzhety-i-elektronika" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/101.0.4951.67 Safari/537.36"
82.147.95.81 - - [21/May/2022:18:28:06 +0300] "GET /static/dist/assets/favicon.ico HTTP/1.1" 403 196 "http://my_domen/new-tracking/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/101.0.4951.67 Safari/537.36"
```

Answer (score 0):

Проблема решена. Надо было в файле `nginx.conf` изменить поле `user`

Comment: А на что поменял то? Там вписано user www-data; и файл под защитой от записи.

Comment: я не помню, root вроде, а может и нет